# Dataset Manipulation in Spark Java API

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `Dataset` DS1 below. I want to build DS2 using Spark Java API.

DS1:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
|  account|    amount  |    type    |
+---------+------------+------------+
| c1      |      100   |      D     |
| c1      |      200   |      C     |
| c2      |      500   |      C     |
```

DS2:

`amount1` is DS1 `amount` where `type = D` and `amount2` is DS1 `amount` where `type = C`

```
+---------+------------+------------+
|  account|    amount1 |   amount2  |
+---------+------------+------------+
| c1      |      100   |      200   |
| c2      |      0     |      500   |
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: the expected dataframe doesn't match with the logic explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For transforming `ds1` to `ds2` in the expected format, you can use following code-

```
val ds2 = ds1
           .withColumn("amount1", when($"type" === "D", $"amount").otherwise(0))
           .withColumn("amount2", when($"type" === "C", $"amount").otherwise(0))
           .select("account", "amount1", "amount2")
           .groupBy($"account")
           .agg(Map("amount1" -> "sum", "amount2" -> "sum"))
```

I hope it helps!